# How to integrate Facebook app with Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-group

We have a website (a wiki) and a Facebook group.  I created an app to let people log into the website with their Facebook ID and that works just fine.  We'd like to have activity from the website show up in the Facebook group, though, or otherwise be posted to a person's timeline (Joe edited this website page, etc.).  How do we go about doing that?  What do we need to change to get the desired functionality?  How can we more closely integrate our Facebook group and our website, perhaps by using the app we have (or any other way)?